# How can I fix my code to avoid returning duplicate pairs while using map in racket?

Tags: duplicates, scheme, racket, transitive-closure

This function should return the transitive closure of L. For Examples:

```
(Transitive-Closure'((a b) (b c) (a c))) ---> '((a b) (b c) (a c))
(Transitive-Closure'((a a) (b b) (c c))) ---> '((a a) (b b) (c c))
(Transitive-Closure'((a b) (b a)))  ---> '((a b) (b a) (a a) (b b)))
(Transitive-Closure'((a b) (b a) (a a)))---> '((a b) (b a) (a a) (b b))
(Transitive-Closure'((a b) (b a) (a a) (b b)))---> '((a b) (b a) (a a) (b b))
(Transitive-Closure'())---> '()
```

Here is what I have in Racket:

```
(define (Transitive-Closure L)
  (apply append
  ; Iterate over each pair (a b) in L,
  (map (lambda (x)
            ;Iterate over each pair (c d) in L,
            (map (lambda (y)
                      (let ([a (car x)]
                            [b (cadr x)]               
                            [c (car y)]
                            [d (cadr y)])
                        ;if b equal to c, and (a d) does not exist in L, it will add (a d) to L . Otherwise, return L.
                        (if  (and (eq? b c) (not (member (list a d) L)))
                             (list a d)
                             (append x))))L)) L)))
```

My code only works when it's not transitive. How can I modify my code to avoid returning duplicate pairs when it's transitive?

For example, my Output:

```
;This is wrong. It should return '((a b)(b c)(a c)) 
(Transitive-Closure '((a b)(b c)(a c))) ---> '((a b) (a b) (a b) (b c) (b c) (b c) (a c) (a c) (a c))
; This is right.
(Transitive-Closure '((a b)(b a)))---> '((a b) (a a) (b b) (b a))
```

Comment: Well, you could use `remove-duplicates` to get rid of the redundant elements...

Comment: The algorithm is wrong anyway - surely you will need some recursion, not just two map calls. Figure that out before worrying about duplicates. For example, consider `((a b) (b c) (c d))`. This should include `(a d)` in the result, but your function as written will not include it.

Comment: You add `x` every time the condition is false, which can happen more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a `map` problem this is a `foldr` problem because you aren't modifying the list in place, you are condensing the list down into one item. That item happens to be a `list` but importantly that list can be smaller than what map can return. Also you can check if you should add or not in another `if` statement based on if the pair already exists in our accumulator.

This works if order doesn't matter (which I am assuming, you just want the set, let me know if this is not the case)

```
(define (Transitive-Closure L)
  ; Iterate over each pair (a b) in L,
  (foldr (lambda (x transitive-pairs)
            ;Iterate over each pair (c d) in L,
            (foldr (lambda (y sofar)
                      (let ([a (car x)]
                            [b (cadr x)]               
                            [c (car y)]
                            [d (cadr y)])
                        ;if b equal to c, and (a d) does not exist in L, it will add (a d) to L . Otherwise, return L.
                        (cond [(and (eq? b c) (not (member (list a d) L))) (cons (list a d) sofar)]
                              [(not (member x sofar)) (cons x sofar)]
                              [else sofar])))
                               transitive-pairs L)) '() L))

(check-expect (Transitive-Closure '((a b) (b c) (a c))) '((a b) (b c) (a c)))
(check-expect (Transitive-Closure '((a a) (b b) (c c))) '((a a) (b b) (c c)))
(check-expect (Transitive-Closure '((a b) (b a))) '((a b) (a a) (b b) (b a)))
(check-expect (Transitive-Closure '((a b) (b a) (a a))) '((a b) (b b) (b a) (a a)))
(check-expect (Transitive-Closure '((a b) (b a) (a a) (b b))) '((a b) (b a) (a a) (b b)))
```